# Regex for floating point?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx to validate a floating point number.  Here's what I've managed thus far:

```
/^[-+]?[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,1})?/
```

The number is valid if:

- Either positive or negative
- Max of 2 digits (tens or hundreds)
- Hundredths digit can't 0 (only 1-9)
- Scale is max of 1
- Decimal value can be 0 or 5 or none at all

So these numbers would be valid, for ex:

- 1.5
- -1.5
- 17.5
- 15
- -3
- 30.5

These numbers would be invalid, for ex:

- 1.57
- 3041.5
- 17.59
- 915
- -1.56
- 05.0

Comment: Is regex the right tool for this?

Comment: Why are you imposing artificial restrictions on what constitutes a float?

Comment: This isn't actually a question.  Which requirements are you stuck on?  Could you provide some rspec code that doesn't pass, or at least some examples where your current regex gives the wrong answer?  Please tell us everything you know instead of making us guess.

Comment: Your regexp will accept `915`. This would be easier to write with a disjunction, or with a lookahead. But only if for some reason you can't use @Arkku's answer.

Comment: Can you describe what other strings your regular expression should match - and equally importantly - should not match. If you can't describe it in words, then give a range of different examples that cover both the common cases, and all the edge cases that you can think of. For each input, state explicitly whether you want it to match or not match.

Comment: Your link is pointing the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments - your first non-zero digit will count, then you add two more - which will now allow three-digit numbers like `915`. To solve this the regexp way ([with your testcases](http://rubular.com/r/OFBdEv0VeP)):

```
^[+-]?(?:(?!0)\d{1,2}|0)(?:\.[05])?$
```

I use negative lookahead `(?!0)` to make sure the first digit is not a zero, then just require the desired number of digits. It also allows `0.5` and similar through the `|0` disjunction. If you prefer `.5`, it'll be this:

```
^[+-]?(?!0)\d{,2}(?:\.[05])?$
```

If you want to disallow `3.0` (allowed by your rules) and only allow `3` (as you imply in the examples), replace the last part:

```
^[+-]?(?:(?!0)\d{1,2}|0)(?:\.5)?$
```

However, this is much less readable than @Arkku's nice `Float(number)`; use regexps if you really need them.

Answer (score 7):

How about `Float(number)` (catch exceptions to detect parse errors) and then verify the floating point number? This will be easier for several of the properties than writing a regex. If you need to force a subset of the syntax accepted by Ruby to be used (why?), check only that part with a regex.

Comment: could you tell how can we catch the exception that is raised when something like is Float("xyz") throws an exception

Comment: @AdityaSanghi `begin`/`rescue` as usual, a brief test in `irb` reveals that `Float("xyz")` throws `ArgumentError`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a whole webpage on validating floats in regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

That said,

- `{1,1}` is equivalent to `{1}` which is equivalent to not putting it at all, so you can remove it
- If you want to make sure that `0.5xyz` doesn't pass, then add a `$` at the end

With the above changes, it'd look like this: `/^[-+]?[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d)?$/`

Answer (score 0):

According to your valid and invalid examples on: [Regex for floating point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186780/regex-for-floating-point)

This regex would work:

```
 ^[+-]?([1-9][0-9]?|0)(\.[05])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[-+]?\d{0,2}(\.[05])?(?!\d)$/
```

Matches when:

- Value is either positive or negative
- magnitude is less than 100. in the range of `(-99.5 to 99.5)`
- Decimal value is `.0` or `.5` or absent (in other words, `.0` or `.5`, or missing)

So these numbers would be valid, for ex:

`1.5`
`-1.5`
`17.5`
`15`
`-3`
`30.5`
`-10.0`
`99.5`

These numbers would be invalid, for ex:

`1.57`
`3041.5`
`17.59`
`915`
`-1.56`
`05.0`
`99.6`