# Regex that accepts floating point numbers and minus (-) sign

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression that will accept only floating point numbers from 0 to 9 and minus sign.

Please help.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Which decimal separator are you using: `,`,`.` or either?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for floating point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186780/regex-for-floating-point)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`

- `^` - start of string
- `[-+]?` - 0 or 1 sign indicator
- `[0-9]*` -  0 or more integers
- `\.` - the character `.` (`.` is used in regex to mean "any character")
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more integers
- `$` - the end of the string

If you are instead using the comma as a decimal seperator, use `,` instead of `\.`

If you are using both/either, you can use `[.,]`

Comment: This only allows for the decimal separator of a period, not any character. Get rid of the backslash to mean "any character". But then that wouldn't be valid for a floating point number. And your last sentence should mention `[.,]`.

Comment: @rmaddy I think you're wrong on both of your statements. I intended to allow for only the . as a decimal separator in the original string, that's why I added the extra sentences. The last sentence works with both [.,] or [\.,] at least on http://regexpal.com

Comment: Any regular expression I've ever worked with, you would just put `[.,]`, not `[\.,]`. But I haven't worked with every possible regex engine. I must have misread something when I commented because when I look at your answer now, most of my comment doesn't seem to apply. Must have been some editing since I commented.

Comment: You can see all [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13686481/revisions) . I hadn't made any changes prior to your request to make an edit.

Comment: A great explanation of how the regex string works for this answer.

Comment: unfortunately `-0` is allowed what is not a real number.

Comment: @PeterRader, [Signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) is a valid concept. This question was language agnostic, but as an example, Swift handles `-0` just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try `^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$`.

This regular expression will match an optional sign, that is either followed by zero or more digits followed by a dot and one or more digits (a floating point number with optional integer part), or followed by one or more digits (an integer).

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html - altered to work with commas as decimal separator

Comment: This won't work in locales that use a decimal separator other than the period.

Comment: This currently allows any character to be used as a separator. `\.`

Comment: Why the duplicate here: `[0-9]+|[0-9]+`

Comment: @JamesWebster No, \. means one character - the period. The period with no backslash means any character.

Comment: Inside square brackets, no character except the closing square bracket and the dash can have a special meaning, so it does **not** mean that any character works as decimal separator.

Comment: rmaddy, I meant to replace with `\.`, but I was wrong anyway. Have a look at @D_4_ni's latest comment

Comment: Also, look closely at the expression, so you'll see that it's not a duplicate. The occurence on the left side from the pipe is just a _part_ of the alternation.

Comment: Well, i just optimized that away. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: There is still one flaw with using such an expression to validate a floating point number. This would allow me to use a comma as a decimal separator when normally my locale uses a period (or visa-versa).

Comment: I know of no way to solve this using just a regular expression.

Comment: @D_4_ni The OP originally had the `ios` tag before you removed it. If this question really should have been "how to validate a floating point number under iOS" then a better solution would be to use an `NSNumberFormatter` and not a regular expression.