# regex numbers in arithmetic expression

Tags: regex

I want to capture all numbers in a string
for example:

```
+================+============+
| string         | match      |
+================+============+
| 5*-33 = 75.3   | 5|-33|75.3 |
+----------------+------------+
| s44+2=7        | 2|7        |
+----------------+------------+
| ii2*-5 = 46    | -5|46      |
+----------------+------------+
| -2*-2.1 =  0.1 | -2|-2.1|0.1|
+================+============+
```

i tried with following expression, but its not working with signed numbers.

```
\b([0-9]+(\.\d+)?)\b
```

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/53etd)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex that accepts floating point numbers and minus (-) sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686237/regex-that-accepts-floating-point-numbers-and-minus-sign)

Comment: You should write a parser. Your test cases are not regular then using regex is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the optional `-`.  `-` is not a number, so you have to capture it separately.

```
\b(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\b
```

Of course, this will have issues with valid expressions such as:

```
4-3
```

But that seems to be a different problem.