# ^[.1-9]*\d$ allows multiple dots

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex for floating point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186780/regex-for-floating-point)

I am trying to use the regex.

**The valid strings are:**

1

11

5

12222222233

1.2

.5

1222.33444

12234.456

0

**Invalid Strings are**

.

-2

san

2s2

S2S

ssss2ssss

25535535TY

But this regex does not qualify to test multiple dots (.)
such as

1......5,

5..2233

1223...5

This accepts these values as valid string. 
Please help me how to fix this issue with reg. 

**Note, the above validation should be passed.**

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is to validate floating point numbers, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that regex: `\d*(\.\d+)?`

**EDIT**

This regex `\d*(\.\d+)?` will allow empty values too.

The updated version: **`\d*(\.)?\d+`** does not have that issue.

Please note that negative values will not be allowed as `\d` matches only digits 0..9

Comment: But it should not allow negative values such as -3

Comment: actually it doesn't... \d is the same as [0-9] so there is no "-" in there.

Answer (score 1):

`^\d*\.?\d*$` should do the trick, but a little thinking and reading more about regex would have told you the same.

Didn't see that . alone or . at the end is not allowed. So `^\d*(\.\d+)?$` sould be just fine

Comment: Man, it's working. Thank you so much...But sorry I am new to regex so could not find the trick. And now I am in learning stage of regex.

Comment: Can you share me some good URL which could explain me the regex better with good examples?

Comment: I think [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) might be a good starting point. There is also some websites like [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com) where you can simply try your expressions.